# Ionic app doesn't install on android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to test my ionic application as a native app on android.

I've tried running the command below as per the ionic documentation

ionic cordova run android

I've also connected up my phone and enabled USB debugging. I get a bunch of output but the app doesn't get installed onto my device.

I've also tried building the application for android but I get no output folder for the apk.

```
Running app-scripts build: --platform android --target cordova
[11:10:08]  build dev started ... 
[11:10:08]  clean started ... 
[11:10:08]  clean finished in 2 ms 
[11:10:08]  copy started ...  
[11:10:08]  deeplinks started ... 
[11:10:08]  deeplinks finished in 27 ms 
[11:10:08]  transpile started ... 
[11:10:12]  transpile finished in 4.13 s 
[11:10:12]  preprocess started ... 
[11:10:12]  preprocess finished in less than 1 ms 
[11:10:12]  webpack started ... 
[11:10:12]  copy finished in 4.38 s 
[11:10:20]  webpack finished in 7.76 s 
[11:10:20]  sass started ... 
Without `from` option PostCSS could generate wrong source map and 
will not find Browserslist config. Set it to CSS file path or to 
`undefined` to prevent this warning.
[11:10:21]  sass finished in 1.28 s 
[11:10:21]  postprocess started ... 
[11:10:21]  postprocess finished in 8 ms 
[11:10:21]  lint started ... 
[11:10:21]  build dev finished in 13.33 s 
> cordova run android
Android Studio project detected

ANDROID_HOME=/Users/markwright/Library/Android/sdk

JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home
studio

[OK] Your app has been deployed.
Did you know you can live-reload changes from your app with --livereload?

[11:10:25]  lint finished in 3.81 s
```

Output of ionic info

```
cli packages: (/Users/markwright/Documents/myApp/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0

global packages:

  cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 

local packages:

  @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.6
  Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 ios 4.5.4
  Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

  Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
  Node              : v6.5.0
  npm               : 5.6.0 
  OS                : OS X El Capitan

Environment Variables:

  ANDROID_HOME : /Users/markwright/Library/Android/sdk

Misc:

  backend : pro
```

The logs I get for running cordova run android --verbose

```
No scripts found for hook "before_run".
No scripts found for hook "before_prepare".
Checking config.xml and package.json for saved platforms that haven't 
been added to the project
Config.xml and package.json platforms are the same. No pkg.json 
modification.
Package.json and config.xml platforms are different. Updating 
config.xml with most current list of platforms.
PlatformApi successfully found for platform android
Android Studio project detected
Checking config.xml for saved plugins that haven't been added to the 
project
Checking for any plugins added to the project that have not been 
installed in android platform  
No differences found between plugins added to project and installed 
in android platform. Continuing...
Generating platform-specific config.xml from defaults for android at/Users/markwright/Documents/myApp/platforms/android/app
/src/main/res/xml/config.xml
Merging project's config.xml into platform-specific android 
config.xml
Merging and updating files from [www, platforms/android/platform_www] 
to platforms/android/app/src/main/assets/www
Wrote out android application name "myApp" to /Users/markwright/Documents/myApp/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/io/ionic/starter/MainActivity.java
Updating icons at platforms/android/app/src/main/res
Updating splash screens at platforms/android/app/src/main/res
This app does not have additional resource files defined
Prepared android project successfully
No scripts found for hook "after_prepare". 
Running command: /usr/libexec/java_home 
Command finished with error code 0: /usr/libexec/java_home 
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/markwright/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home
```

studio

Comment: what do you mean? `[OK] Your app has been deployed.`?

Comment: That message appears whenever I run the command but the application never appears on my mobile.

Comment: weirrd.. does `adb devices` command detect your device?

Comment: also what is output if `ionic info`?

Comment: Yep adb gives me my device and device id

Comment: I've just updated the question to reflect the output for the ionic info

Comment: try `cordova run android --verbose` and check if you get logs

Comment: I'm getting logs. I've updated the question with the output.

Comment: maybe java_home isnt setup correctly.. verify with `cordova requirements` command

Comment: Oh my god, thank you sooo much!! Running that command indicated there was a problem with gradle not being installed correctly, I've now installed gradle and everything works just fine.

Comment: @LAB does ionic cordova build android was sucessful

Comment: Yeah, it works fine now.